# Edit format of text file in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, debian

I have this text file :

```
z1 x2 c3 v4 b5 n6 m7 a8
```

and i want to reformat it to:

```
z1
x2
c3
v4
b5
n6
m7
a8
```

in the Linux Terminal .
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace spaces with newlines using [sed](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html)

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' my_file > my_file_reformatted
```

You can find the syntax of `sed` on the manual page, but essentially you put the character string you want to replace between the first pair of `/`, and the string to replace it with between the second one.

You also don't nessesarily need to use `/` as the delimiter, it could be any other character.

Answer (score 0):

To replace all whitespace with newlines, try

```
tr -s ' \t' '\n' <file >newfile
```